# Cannot run FastAPI Docker image : Docker ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: docker

This is my application structure:

```
project/
├── Dockerfile
├── example_api
│   └── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

COPY ./example_api /app/src
COPY ./requirements.txt /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "example_api.main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--reload"]
```

building with

```
docker build -t siddesh-fastapi:0.1 .
```

running with

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 --name siddesh-test-api siddesh-fastapi:0.1
```

error message

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using watchgod
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 68, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1501, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 76, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 448, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example_api'
```

I guess I am missing something in the Dockerfile?

Comment: You `COPY example_api` into a `src` subdirectory, but that's not on the default `$PYTHONPATH`.  Can you `COPY example_api/ example_api/` instead, so the path relative to the current directory matches the Python module name?

Comment: It Worked! Thanks.